# Calculate average based on number of inputs in C#

Tags: c#

I am displaying three text box, which get only numbers.
User may enter value in one text box or two or three in any order.
I want to calculate the average of value entered in those text boxes in C#.

For example. if any one text box contain values, average must be calculate based on 1 (value/1).

if two text box contain values, average must be calculate with 2 (value1+value2)/2

if three text boxes contain values, average must be calculate with 3
(value1+value2+value3)/3.

any one know how to achieve this with less code?

Comment: less code than what?

Comment: Yes, I think everyone will understand the concept of average :D But what have you tried so far - where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

You could put those values into an array or list and use LINQ's `Enumerable.Average`. Or calculate it with following query that uses `int.TryParse` and presumes that the TextBoxes are in the same container control(like a `Panel` or `GroupBox`):

```
int value = 0;
double average = TextBoxPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() // get all TextBoxes from this panel
    .Where(t => int.TryParse(t.Text, out value))  // which Text is parsable to int
    .Select(t => value)                           // select the value that contains the parsed int
    .Average();                                   // use Enumerable.Average to calculate the average
```

Answer (score 1):

The most trivial approach would be to create a list to contain the values, and leverage the framework to calculate the average of the numbers contained in that list.

In steps, as to not spoon-feed you copy-pasteable code:

1. Create a numeric list variable
2. For each textbox:

   1. Check if the textbox contains text
   2. If so, try to parse it as a number
   3. When that succeeds, add the number to the list
3. Calculate the average of the numbers in the list

Relevant reading material:

- [Get all controls of a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type)
- [Convert textbox text to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548875/convert-textbox-text-to-integer)
- [MSDN: `List<T>.Average()` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910354(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: ++ for not spoon-feeding as i did and providing all necessary informations anyway ;)

Comment: @Tim thanks! :) Your LINQ/Fluent answer is succint and does the trick, but might not be that understandable for someone new to programming. ;)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. This list is working perfectly