# how to convert text field value to real number to store in database

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal id = decimal.Parse(txt_ID.Text);
    string name = txt_name.Text;
    double agg = double.Parse(txt_aggregate.Text); 

    //string cmd = "update Student set Aggregate=" + "'" + aggregate + "'" + " where ID:
    string cmd = "udate student set Agrregate=@aggreagte where Id=@id ";
    command = new Sq1Command(cmd,con); 

    //register
    command.Parameters.Add("@aggregate",SqlDbType.Real);
    command.Parameters.Add("@id",SqlDbType.Decima1,10); 

    //submit 

    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = txt_ID.Text;
    // float agg=float.Parse(txt_aggregate.Text);
    command.Parameters["@aggregate"] = agg; 

    // DisplayGrid(cmd);I
```

How do I convert text number to real in to store value in database?

Comment: google? "Convert text to number c#" for example. You have to show what you´ve tried so far to get some help. You can´t expect the users here to write your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert textbox text to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548875/convert-textbox-text-to-integer)

Answer (score 0):

As [HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528063/himbrombeere) said, showing what you have done/tried so far will help to direct you tho the right solution.

But if what you are tying to convert a string to number(eg.`int`) you could use

`int.Parse("10")` or `int.TryParse("10")`

For the differences between the two methods and more details, refer to msdn documentations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

> ..If the string is not in a valid format, Parse throws an exception
>   whereas TryParse returns false.

Comment: I have written in code variable agg  is parsed int to double but while storing in data base I have stored in real valued data type. so I got error not implicitly converting to sql data type!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!