# Using Table Adapter, Converting textbox string to int to match my database data type for the given field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created an SQL database within visual studio, now when trying to insert values from the web app into the database, within my insert statement, I obviously have to convert the textbox strings to the data type of that in the database. How?

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.TableBookTableAdapter bookTableAdapter;
        bookTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TableBookTableAdapter();



        bookTableAdapter.Insert(ISBN: txtISBN.Text, courseID: txtCourseID.Text, bookTitle: txtBookTitle.Text, Ancillary: txtAncillary.Text,
            bookActive: true, ActiveDate: activeCalendar.SelectedDate, InactiveDate: inactiveCalendar.SelectedDate, Author: txtAuthor.Text, Imprint: txtImprint.Text, 
            Publisher: txtPublisher.Text, EditionDate: txtEditionDate.Text, VendorISBN: txtVendorISBN.Text, p1: txtP1.Text, eBookAvailable: true, eISBN: txtEISBN.Text, Notes: txtNotes.Text);
```

The error I get is no more than "Cannot convert from "string" to "int", Ive tried to convert it with what i've found online and cannot seem to come up with anything that works

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int anInteger;
        anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(txtVendorISBN.Text);
        anInteger = int.Parse(txtVendorISBN.Text);
    }
```

Above is What I tried on page load to convert the information within the textbox to int but the syntax error still states that it cannot convert from string to int.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using int.parse() for your conversion?

Comment: Yes that was attempted. I just feel like i'm missing a step because its interacting with the database

Comment: Post your code for insert.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are converting every value that needs to be an int.  You may have missed one.

Comment: No I havent converted it yet! I've tried to use int.Parse() and it didn't work. There are 3 I have to convert the ISBN and the 10Digit ISBN. and what I've tried hasnt worked at all

Comment: So post the relevant code which you tried but didn't worked.

Comment: see this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548875/convert-textbox-text-to-integer>